# How to make hamburger menu dissapear after clicking link with react scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scroll, navbar, hamburger-menu

I am trying to make my hamburger menu work with react scroll. It works as it should but when i click the links the menu does not dissapear. I  tried the below but it makes it worst.

```
import React from 'react';
// import nav data
import { navData } from '../data';
// import components
import Socials from './Socials';
import { Link} from "react-scroll";
import { useState } from 'react';

const NavMobile = () => {
  // destructure nav data
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true)
  const { items } = navData;
  return (
    

   
    <nav className={`${isActive? "w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-evenly overflow-hidden" : ""}`}>
      <ul className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-y-6 py-6 mb-8'>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Link
            activeClass="active"
            to={item.href}
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={500}
            >
            <li key={index} onClick={setIsActive(!isActive)}>
              <a className='text-2xl font-primary uppercase' href={item.href} >
                {item.name}
                
              </a>
            </li>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className='text-2xl'>
        <Socials />
      </div>
    </nav>
    
      
  );
};

export default NavMobile;
```

I just can't find out what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional classNames for your `<nav>` don't need to be wrapped in the  template literal `${}` the line is instead written as follows

```
<nav className={isActive ? "w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-evenly overflow-hidden" : ""}>
```

Your onClick handler should also have it's own defined function.

```
const handleClick = () => {setIsActive(!isActive)}
```

And then be parsed to the onClick method of the `<li>`

```
<li key={index} onClick={handleClick}>
```

See [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-onclick-pass-event-and-parameter#:~:text=To%20pass%20an%20event%20and,event%20and%20parameter%20to%20handleClick%20](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-onclick-pass-event-and-parameter#:%7E:text=To%20pass%20an%20event%20and,event%20and%20parameter%20to%20handleClick%20). for more help. This is necessary because you are parsing the **function** to the onClick method rather than the **result** of the function.